# ¿Cómo generar PDF con React y Firebase?

Tags: firebase, reactjs, pdf

me gustaría que me ayudaran con un problema que quiero resolver.
Hice un proyecto con React.js y Firebase para almacenar los datos y quiero generar un PDF con todos los libros registrados, ya estuve buscando y no he encontrado una forma de poder adaptarlo, si alguien sabe como realizarlo se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hasta ahora que haz intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar jsPdf (https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) **si no requieres compatibilidad con varios browsers**, ya que ninguna libreria de las que he probado dan el mismo resultado en diferentes browsers.

Ejemplo con jspdf

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-monad-k8gnh

Para descargar el PDF debes permitir la descarga de la ventama emergente de ese ejemplo en codesandbox

El código lo puedes ajustar a tus necesitades, para imprimir tablas, imagenes o lo q necesites

La opción que más me gusta es phantomjs pero lo debes usar en el servidor con Nodejs y en este caso no hay problema con los browsers porque la generación del PDF se hace en el lado del servidor.

Este seria un ejemplo:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

Lo q debes hacer es crear un paǵina q sea accesible por phantomjs, le puedes configurar cookies si tienes autenticación o un token JWT.